# Orderby custom field altera o Loop no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

No meu blog, tenho diferentes categorias, e em cada post eu criei um custom field com a key `posicao` com valores numéricos. Este é o código que possuo

```
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'meta_key'          => 'posicao',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'ASC'
    ));

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 

            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                the_content();>     

            endwhile; 

            wp_reset_postdata();

            else: echo "Não existem artigos";

            endif;
```

Porém, na página das categorias, ele não organiza mais por categoria, e sim, pela ordem da key ´posicao´, mas, mostra todos os posts de todas as categorias.

Assim, na página de uma categorias, não mostra só os posts da categoria, mas se tiro as variáveis, como no exemplo abaixo, ele mostra apenas os posts da categorias, porém sem a ordem pela `posicao`

```
    if (have_posts() ) : 

            while (have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui realizar com

```
if (is_category( )) {
  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
  $yourcats =  $yourcat->slug;

 }

query_posts('category_name='. $yourcats.'&meta_key=posicao&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1'); 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    the_content();

endwhile; else: endif;
```